# in __getattr__ raise AttributeError(attr) AttributeError: to_text

Tags: python-3.x, dns

This program is suppose to return the Domain Name and MX resolved against the domain. BUT it gives this error, not sure what I have been doing wrong.
I am receiving this error: **getattr**
raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: to_text

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import socket
import dns.resolver
import re

domain = ['gmail.com' , 'hotmail.com' , 'abcfder.abc']

#function for mx
def getmx (domain):
    nomx= "no.mx.resolved."
try:
    result = dns.resolver.query(domain, 'MX')
    #for mailexchange in result:
    return (domain, result.to_text())
    #break
except dns.exception.DNSException as e:
    if isinstance(e, dns.resolver.NXDOMAIN):
    return (domain, nomx)
    #break

#function to remove '\n' from list

def clean (domainname):
    tmpstr = domainname
    domainname = tmpstr.strip()
    return (domainname)

#loop to keep sending domain names to MX function till EOF
x=0
while x<len(domain):
    strtmp = domain[x]
    d = clean(strtmp)
    #print (d)
    mx=getmx(d)
    print (mx)
    x=x+1   
f.close()
```

Comment: I would say to_text() does not exist in the object returned by dns.resolver.query

Comment: This was working fine without adding exception handling before @luis.parravicini

Answer (score 1):

dns.resolver.query returns an [Answer](http://www.dnspython.org/docs/1.15.0/dns.resolver.Answer-class.html) object which doesn't have a `to_text()` method, but Answer has a response attribute which has `to_text()`, try:

```
result.response.to_text()
```

Comment: This Works. BUT( How to get only "5 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com" out of whole response?)

'gmail.com', 'id 41739\nopcode QUERY\nrcode NOERROR\nflags QR RD RA\n;QUESTION\ngmail.com. IN MX\n;ANSWER\ngmail.com. 675 IN MX 30 alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.\ngmail.com. 675 IN MX 5 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.\ngmail.com. 675 IN MX 10 alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.\ngmail.com. 675 IN MX 20 alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.\ngmail.com. 675 IN MX 40 alt4.gmail-smtp-

Comment: Haven't used dnspython myself, but you could check [Message](http://www.dnspython.org/docs/1.15.0/dns.message.Message-class.html)'s documentation to extract the information needed

Comment: Thanks for all help here. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a for loop on the variable that receives the response from the request. For example:

```
answer = dns.resolver.resolve(domain, 'A')
for record in answer:
    print(record.to_text())
```